# How can I dynamically filter links from org-export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I've got a handle on how to use :filter functions but this doesn't work:

```
(defun my-filter-links (s backend info)                                                                                                                                    
  "Filter out links from lines ending in :ignore"                                                                                                                          
  (let*                                                                                                                                                                    
    ((props (nth 1 (get-text-property 1 :parent s)))                                                                                                                     
     (begin (plist-get props :begin)))                                                                                                                                   
     (save-excursion                                                                                                                                                     
       (goto-char begin)                                                                                                                                                 
       (if (re-search-forward (rx ":ignore") (line-end-position) t)                                                                                                      
           (progn                                                                                                                                                        
             (message "hit: %s" (buffer-substring-no-properties begin (point)))                                                                                          
             "flibble")                                                                                                                                                  
         s))))                                                                                                                                                           


(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-test-export 'ascii                                                                                                                  
  :filters-alist                                                                                                                                                           
  '((:filter-link . my-filter-links)))


;; Export everyting from * Exporting                                                                                                                                       

(save-excursion                                                                                                                                                            
  (goto-char (point-min))                                                                                                                                                  
  (when (re-search-forward "* Exporting")                                                                                                                                  
    (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
    (org-export-as 'my-test-export t nil t '(:num nil :p nil))))
```

I can see the message when I hit a link but the link still appears in the export.

Comment: A filter is supposed to modify its input on the way to its output. I don;t see any such modification in your code.

Comment: @Nick my-filter-links returns "flibble" when it finds a link on a line where :ignore is at the end, otherwise it returns the un-mangled s. While I see the the (message) in the logs none of the links are affected.